# How to solve error "Default Activity Not Found" occurred when starting my application from Service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I need to start my **Android Application** using **Service** and after start an **Activity** from that **Service**. Firstly I created **Sample Application** by referring **Stack Overflow**. I created **StartReceiver** class to start **Service**.

```
public class StartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }
}
```

This is my **Service** class.

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
        Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intents);
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    }
}
```

This is my **Activity** class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello........", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

this is my **AndroidManifest** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.onbitlabs.runwithoutactivity" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"

android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name=".StartReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

When I Run the Application, Android Studio gives **Error running app: Default Activity not found**. 
**How could I Fix this Error ?**

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: I tried but it is not solved this error

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your Activity in manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I need to start my application from service not from activity.

Comment: Try to use the service context using "this", instead of "getBaseContext()". This is the only difference I can see.

Answer (score 1):

`android.intent.action.MAIN` means that this activity is the entry point of the application, i.e. when you launch the application, this activity is created.

`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` says that entry point should be listed in the application launcher

So you need to add that in your manifest. Just change:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

to

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I need to start my application from Service. and after MainActivity need to start from that Service.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link. I hope this helps

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjsytHAhLLXAhWDuo8KHa4kAjoQFgg2MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F15825081%2Ferror-default-activity-not-found&usg=AOvVaw0HThKZRxKk9ET-NdnVwEfR